# How to set WHM to Save Back Up to PC?

Tags: backups

First I would need to set an FTP server in my PC. However, my ISP gives semi dynamic IP. Is that even possible. I suppose we can have a domain name point to the IP.

Is that even possible?

After that what?

Comment: Did you tried `rsync` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly use some sort of DNS service to point a domain to your IP address. However, an easier way would likely be just to set WHM to store the backup locally, and then setup a script on your local machine to `rsync` or `scp` the backup once a day. If you want to make sure that the backups don't pile up, you could include something in that script to then delete whatever backup is currently sitting on the server AFTER it's been rsync'd.

The rsync should be easy enough, but [here's some help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243750/how-can-i-automate-running-commands-remotely-over-ssh) on executing shell commands remotely.